# get data attribute of dynamically generated selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two select boxes generated after an AJAX request:

```
$("#job_id").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'id': id },
    }).done(function(data) {
        var contc = "";
        var contc2 = "N/A";
        var seal = "";
        var seal2 = "N/A";
        $.each(data, function(i, d) {
            contc += "" + d.container_no + "";
            contc2 += "" + d.container_no + "";
        });
        $("#container1").html(contc);
        $("#container2").html(contc2);
        // console.log("done"); 
    }).fail(function() {
        $("#container1").html("");
        $("#container2").html("");
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'id': id },
    }).done(function(d) {
        $("#cont_pickup").val(d.id);
        $("#cont_pickup_name").val(d.name);
    }).fail(function() {
        $("#cont_pickup").val("");
        $("#cont_pickup_name").val("");
    });
});
```

I want the `data-seal` value. For that I wrote:

```
$("#container1,#container2").change(function() {
    $("#cont_seal_1").val($("#container1").data('seal'));
    $("#cont_seal_2").val($("#container2").data('seal'));
});
```

However it returns `undefined`. How can I get `data-seal`?

Comment: format your code.

Comment: Please add your HTML. If the `#containerX` elements are `<select>` then you're not adding the `option` elements to them correctly. Where is `data-seal` set?

Comment: I added it in my post code but when you format it, its been removed. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
$("#container1,#container2").change(function() {
    $("#cont_seal_1").val($("#container1 option:selected").data('seal'));
    $("#cont_seal_2").val($("#container2 option:selected").data('seal'));
});
```

Comment: great ;) It was necessary to use selector of **selected** option.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `data-seal` of `selected option` not from the `select`

```
$("#container1,#container2").change(function() {
    $("#cont_seal_1").val($("#container1 option:selected").data('seal'));
    $("#cont_seal_2").val($("#container2 option:selected").data('seal'));
});
```

Or

```
$("#container1,#container2").change(function() {
    $("#cont_seal_1").val($("#container1 option:selected").attr('data-seal'));
    $("#cont_seal_2").val($("#container2 option:selected").attr('data-seal'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your items are dynamically added try to read about jQuery `on()` or `live()`.

example:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
 console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```